# Cannot Connect to WiFi using Broadcom wireless

Tags: wireless, broadcom, b43

Forgive my noob-ignorance, but I tried doing the research before asking here.

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 on an original MacBook Air and I didn't see any networks in the WiFi dropdown even though wireless seems to be on.

I don't have a wired connection, so I have to download drivers on another computer and install them manually.

I looked up my wireless card and it says that it is a Broadcom with a PCI.ID of **14e4:4328 (rev 05)**. Then I looked up the driver in the table and it said that I needed to use "*firmware-b43-installer*". In another thread, I found out that, for Ubuntu 16.04,  I needed to use *b43-fwcutter_019-2_amd64.deb* to install the driver in *broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2*.

When I install this and reboot, I still don't see any WiFi networks showing up.

Is there something else that I need to do? What other info do you need?

[EDIT] Here is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:008b]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: ssb, wl
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the erroneously installed `wl` driver. Run

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and then reboot or run

```
sudo modprobe b43
```

Comment: This solved this problem. OMG, my head was about to explode with the amount of information on this issue. :-)  Now the result of the lspci command shows `Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge`. Thank you so much @Pilot6 for your quick and accurate responses.

Comment: Did this solution stand the test of time? I've been having trouble with this on an A1237, same adapter ID. I got wifi working once or twice but then after a power cycle it stopped working and shows as "Wifi Disconnected" every time. Wondering if the final post at https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=223778&start=20 will fix it