# Broadcom wireless driver [14e4:4328] (rev 05) on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, broadcom

Second update: It was too good to be true.  I installed hplip, which required a reboot. After the reboot, the card no longer sees any ssid.  Another reboot
does not help. I also used ifconfig to shut down and restart the driver, but no love.  I also found this post from a couple of years ago:
[Wifi connectivity for same card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947960/cannot-connect-to-wifi-using-broadcom-wireless?rq=1). It was also answered by Pilot6, but a comment at the bottom shows that at least one person had the same problems I have, that it is does not work after reboot.

UPDATE: @Pilot6 requested more information, which I provided. I did yet
another reboot, and that seems to have done the trick, for some reason.
I did not try anything else to fix the problem (except read about it).
Apparently, a third reboot was all that was necessary. It seems to be
working now.  If there are stability problems, I will report back here.
Otherwise, this chip could be added to the list with the right fix.

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on an old macbook air with core 2 duo.
The wireless card works, but is not seen by the new os at all.  Thanks
for the attention to the problem, @Pilot6!

I have read through the (excellent) instructions on getting these cards working on linux.  There is an extensive list for different cards, but not this particular revision.  So, I followed the recommendations and did the following:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo update-pciids
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

Then rebooted.  This allows the OS to see the card, but the card could not find any networks.  So, I also tried

```
sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe b43
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

I could detect no change in behavior, however.  Linux still sees the card,
but the card sees no networks.

Per the request below:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:0090]
        Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
        Kernel modules: ssb
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

And:

```
    $ dmesg | grep b43
[   10.016852] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4321 WLAN found (core revision 12)
[   10.060024] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 5, Type 4 (N), Revision 2
[   10.060034] b43-phy0: Found Radio: Manuf 0x17F, ID 0x2055, Revision 4, Version 0
[   12.100273] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
[  143.844061] b43-phy0 ERROR: DMA RX reset timed out
[  144.124077] b43-phy0 ERROR: DMA TX reset timed out
[  151.461976] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4321 WLAN found (core revision 12)
[  151.504365] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 5, Type 4 (N), Revision 2
[  151.504379] b43-phy0: Found Radio: Manuf 0x17F, ID 0x2055, Revision 4, Version 0
[  151.788099] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
[ 1564.636034] b43-phy0 ERROR: DMA RX reset timed out
[ 1564.912024] b43-phy0 ERROR: DMA TX reset timed out
[ 1570.776212] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
```

And:

```
$ dpkg -l *b43*
```

dpkg-query: no packages found matching b43-fwcutter_015-9_amd64.deb

dpkg-query: no packages found matching b43-fwcutter_019-2_amd64.deb

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Actually `bcmwl-kernel-source` is the right one.

Comment: I don't think so for rev 5, but I am not quite sure. @mikewhatever

Comment: @JDS Please also add output of `dmesg | grep b43`.

Comment: I quote from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx): `          4321 Dualband     0x14e4      0x4328`.

Comment: Well, that file is not always accurate, but it worth a try. @mikewhatever

Comment: @JDS Did you try `bcmwl-kernel-source`?

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, I tried that originally, but it never saw the card. Then I tried the steps outlined above. After a few reboots, it worked.

Comment: ..and then stopped working on a subsequent reboot.

Comment: I can also confirm that purging all broadcom drivers and repeating the above installation works after rebooting, but then fails on subsequent reboots. The card is seen by ubuntu, but the card sees no routers.

Comment: Could it be from secure boot, or EFI, or whatever it is that mac uses?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] your post to include the output of `dpkg -l *b43*` Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: OK, @ElderGeek, I have added it.  Also, on this particular reboot, I have wireless again. So far, I cannot find any pattern to predict when it will or won't work.  Thanks!

Comment: Your output is unexpected. Can you try again with exactly the command I requested?

Comment: I cut and pasted and tried again, with the same output.

Answer (score 4):

I have [14e4:4328] (rev 05) on Ubuntu 18.04 and my issue was that I could see wireless networks but could not connect to them (error message "activation of network connection failed").

I was able to resolve it with just the below steps:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo update-pciids
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

I have HP DV9000 [14e4:4328] (rev 05) on Ubuntu 20.04 and my issue was that I could not see the wireless adapter.

I was able to resolve it with just the below steps:

**sudo apt update**

**sudo apt upgrade**

**sudo apt-get purge** **bcmwl-kernel-source** *(this step told me that it did not find any bcmwl-kernel-source to purge)*

**sudo update-pciids**

**sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer**

**reboot**